# How to update deeply nested array document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to update this attached[image]
Mongo collection using the following controller, but getting **bad value** mongoError. Should I need to change the Model or are any changes needed in the current controller?

```
updateMarkCard = (req, res) => {
  const reg = "66";
  const sem = "sem-1";
  const Ia = "IA-1";
  MarksCardList.find({ student_id: reg }).exec((err, data) => {
    if (err) res.status(400).json({ message: "Student Not Found" });
    if (data) {
   
      const findSem = data[0].marksCard_list.find((el) => {
        return el.semister === sem;
      });

      const findIA =
        findSem &&
        findSem.IA.find((el) => {
          return el.IA_type === Ia;
        });
          
      MarksCardList.findOneAndUpdate(
        {
          student_id: reg,
          "marksCard_list._id": findSem._id,
        },
        {
          $set: {
            "marksCard_list.$[marksCard_list].IA.$[IA].marks": req.body.marks,
          },
        },
        {
          arrayFilters: [
            { "marksCard_list._id": findSem._id },
            { "IA._id": findIA._id },
          ],
        }
      ).exec((er, data) => {
        if (er) res.status(400).json({ ...er });
        if (data) res.status(400).json({ data });
      });
    }
  });
};
```

Comment: hardcode this line `"marksCard_list.$[marksCard_list].IA.$[IA].marks": [1,2,3],` and check

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath Didn't work, sir.

Comment: Working in mongo shell?

Comment: @RajdeepDebnath No, I'm working in Atlas.

Comment: I mean are you connecting to Atlas via mongoos from nodejs or mongo shell?